# A physical algorithm that finds all integer partitions of a number

Tags: algorithms, education, integer-partitions

If this is not the right forum for this question let me know.

I am looking for a `physical algorithm` that can be easily followed by anyone not knowing much mathematics to get integer partitions of a number.

I have come up with the following way - but there is an issue (described later).

Suppose I want to [divide number 11 into all its integer partitions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integer%20partition%20%20of%2011) (order is not important).

For finding `partitions of size 2` we do following.

Take 11 coins of identical widths. Take a paper. Write `1` and `2` on it

```
1    2
```

Below the first number, keep all 11 coins one upon another to make a tower of height `11`. This is represented as -

```
1      2

11c   0c
```

Now, shift `1` coin from first column to second column.

```
1      2

10c   1c
```

Here, height of tower 1 = 10, height of tower2 = 1

Keep on doing this, only if `Height of tower 1 >= Height of tower2`

On each step of the algorithm, we get new integer partition.

- This "physical algorithm" is easy to understand by anyone knowing
  basic mathematics.
- Preferrably, each step in the physical algorithm must show a new
  partitioning way.
- There should be an end condition to the algorithm.
- When the algorithm reaches end condition, all possible partitioning
  ways must have been shown.

If we now want to find [all partitions of size 3](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integer%20partition%20%20of%2011%20of%20size%203), the problem gets a bit tricky.

We have 3 towers, with following restrictions 
`Height of tower 1 >= Height of tower2 >= Height of tower3`

But thing is, there are certain positions, from which we cannot go to next stage without destroying earlier stage - what do I mean by this? See below

`Step1`

```
1      2     3

9c    1c     1c
```

`Step2`

```
1      2     3

8c    2c     1c
```

`Step3`

```
1      2     3

7c    3c     1c
```

`Alternative Step3`

```
1      2     3

7c    2c     2c
```

At `step 3` the algorithm creates two branches - people could either put new coin in tower2 or tower1. **How should the algorithm statements be written so that by the time the algorithm is finished, all partitions of size 3 are known?**

**If you could come up with a new algorithm, that's welcome too!**

Comment: `either put new coin in tower2 or tower1` from 1 to either 2 or *3*

Answer (score 2):

Let us aim at generating the partitions in the following order (below, for $n=6$):

$$
\begin{align*}
& 6 \\
& 5 \, 1 \\
& 4 \, 2 \\
& 4 \, 1 \, 1 \\
& 3 \, 3 \\
& 3 \, 2 \, 1 \\
& 3 \, 1 \, 1 \, 1 \\
& 2 \, 2 \, 2 \\
& 2 \, 2 \, 1 \, 1 \\
& 2 \, 1 \, 1 \, 1 \, 1 \\
& 1 \, 1 \, 1 \, 1 \, 1 \, 1
\end{align*}
$$
We start with the partition $n$.

To generate a new partition, identify the last non-1 entry in the preceding partition (if there is no such, we’re done); reduce it by 1, and delete all following entries; complete it to a partition by repeatedly adding the maximum possible number, under the constraint that the partition is non-increasing.

You can check that this indeed generates all partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with following algorithm for finding partitions of size 3. It may be generalized to size `N`, but I'm not 100% sure.

**Initial Setup**

A paper with 3 numbers, 1,2 and 3 written on it.

11 coins.

1 coin in tower1, 1 coin in tower2, 9 coins in tower3.

This is represented as

```
[step1] 1 1 9
```

**Algorithm**
This algorithm is a series of steps. Some of the steps are termed "starting positions". Once a starting position is reached, an operation `O1` must be performed to reach next step - while satisfying a certain condition `C0`. Then we repeat that operation multiple times. If that partular condition `C0` cannot be satisfied, we go to the next starting position via operaiton `O2`.

`Condition C0` = **Height of tower1 <= Height of tower2 <= Height of tower3**

`Operation O1` = **Shift one coin from last tower to second-last tower while `condition C0` is satisfied. If `C0` cannot be satisfied do operation `O2`**

`Operation O2` = **Shift one coin from last tower to first tower. Then shift coins from second-last tower to last-tower until
`Height of tower1 = Height of tower2`**

`Termination condition` = **If after performing `operation O2`, `condition C0` cannot be satisfied, algorithm is terminated and that coin distribution is discarded.**

**Algorithm demonstration**

**Initial Starting position**

```
[step1] 1 1 9
```

`Condition C0`
`Height of tower1 <= Height of tower2 <= Height of tower3`

`Operation O1` -> Shift one coin from last tower to second-last tower while `condition C0` is satisfied.

```
[step2] 1 2 8
[step3] 1 3 7
[step4] 1 4 6
[step5] 1 5 5
```

Now, we can no longer perform `operation O1` without disobeying `condition C0`. So we shift to next starting position via `operation O2` which modifies coin distribution according to some conditions.

`Operation O2` - 
Shift one coin from last tower to first tower
Shift coins from second-last tower to last-tower until
`Height of tower1 = Height of tower2`

**If `condition C0` cannot be satisfied at this stage - algorithm is terminated. Otherwise we go forward as below**

After performing `operation O2` we reach next starting position as below

```
[step6] 2 2 7
```

Now, a series of `O1` operations takes us through -

```
[step7] 2 3 6
[step8] 2 4 5
```

Now `C0` cannot be obeyed after performing `operation O1`, so we apply `operation O2`

```
[step9] 3 3 5
```

Then another `O1`

```
[step10] 3 4 4
```

Now `C0` cannot be obeyed after performing `O1`, so we apply `O2`

```
4 4 3
```

**`C0` cannot be obeyed by above distribution, so algorithm has terminated and last coin position `4 4 3` is discarded.**

Thus we get all 10 ways to partition 11 into 3 summands.